# Included module cannot call instance variable of parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, I have a class that defined a instance variable:

```
 class ApplicationApi < Grape::API
    include WithGrapeLogging
    @api_environment_name = "Android"
  end
```

Here is my custom module, in this custom module, I called instance variable of above class:

```
require 'grape_logging'
module WithGrapeLogging
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
      logger.formatter = GrapeLogging::Formatters::Default.new

      use GrapeLogging::Middleware::RequestLogger,
        logger: logger,
        formatter: GrapeLoggerFormatter.new(@api_environment_name),
        include: [ GrapeLogging::Loggers::Response.new,
                   GrapeLogging::Loggers::FilterParameters.new,
                   GrapeLogging::Loggers::ClientEnv.new,
                   GrapeLogging::Loggers::RequestHeaders.new ]
  end
end
```

I don't know what that variable is null. Please figure me how.

Comment: `api_environment_variable` is not the same as `api_environment_name`

Comment: @AlejandroC. Edited. I'm sory, just my typo.

Comment: have you tried setting the `@api_environment_name = "Android"` before `include WithGrapeLogging`?

Comment: Try defining the variable first and then include the module

Comment: Wow. thanks so much. it worked. I don't know Ruby take care about order at import before.

Comment: I don't know why. but some of my code, I always include at very first of class, and still can use instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-include) method's source code:

```
               static VALUE
rb_mod_include(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE module)
{
    int i;
    ID id_append_features, id_included;

    CONST_ID(id_append_features, "append_features");
    CONST_ID(id_included, "included");

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        Check_Type(argv[i], T_MODULE);
    while (argc--) {
        rb_funcall(argv[argc], id_append_features, 1, module);
        rb_funcall(argv[argc], id_included, 1, module);
    }
    return module;
}
```

We can see that for each of the arguments passed to `Module#include`, it calls the block passed to `included` (via `rb_funcall`)

When you `include` your module on the second line of your class definition, it calls the block provided to `included` in your module definition. When it's running through that block, Ruby identifies that `@api_environment_name` has not been defined and throws an error. If you put the definition of that instance variable *before* you `include` the module, it will recognize it.

Comment: thanks. can you give me ruby document explain about this. I haven't learned this from any document I ever have.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự I just edited in a reference to the Ruby source. I can't seem to find too much else describing this.